# Windows 10: Keyboard type rate extremely slow after boot

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, lag

I have upgraded my computer using a core i5 2500K from Windows 7 x64 to WIndows 10 x64, and the whole system runs fast and reliable, with one exception: after booting from SSD, which takes only about 10 seconds, my keyboard is really slow for the first 1 or 2 minutes right after booting. "Slow" means that when I start notepad, and type some characters, it takes a second for each character to appear on screen. Everything else is fast, including mouse movement, starting programs, only keyboard input is that slow. After 1 to 2 minutes, the keyboard suddenly behaves normally again.

This happens with every kind of keyboard I connect, no matter if I use the legacy PS/2 adapter, or USB.

Does anybody have any idea what might be the cause of this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally figured out the culprit: it was some original Microsoft software I had once installed called "Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center" that came with my Microsoft keyboard. The process name is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center\ipoint.exe
```

After killing that process, everything works smoothly again.

Answer (score 8):

This might be interesting for some people experiencing this problem: in my case, it was caused by EVGA PrecisionX running on startup - the first +-30 seconds were showing terrible lags when typing, waiting around 2 seconds for a letter to appear.

Comment: I've had this same issue for years and I always suspected EVGA PrecisionX program was the cause. It's very annoying but it's good to know I'm not the only one

Comment: Could be! The problem disappeared after I got a new GPU and uninstalled Precision X.

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalled Mouse and keyboard center and my lag delay in typing during startup on windows 10 was fixed.

Hope more people having this issue find this fix. Night and day difference.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your answer to explain how you fixed the issue in more detail?

Comment: This is a ME Too for the accepted answer.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Temporary typing lags are often caused by Windows downloading updates "in the background", or some other automatically updated software on your computer downloading updates.

Comment: This just seems like a random comment, considering the problem was caused by something else entirely, as reported by the author over a year ago.