# On a Windows 10 ASUS laptop, on startup, I can only type so fast

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

When I boot up my laptop (which by the way boots really fast), everything is okay even when typing my password. Then, as soon as desktop shows, the typing (and only that it seems) gets really slow.

What I mean by "slow" is if I write for example "Hello world!" in notepad the characters will appear one by one with seconds between them. After a few minutes it eventually catches up and writes evrything (if the sentence was long enough of course), and then there's no more issue at all.

It's not only letters, for example for "windows+r" (execute) to run i need to have both keys pressed for a few seconds, until the windows shows up.

I bought the laptop with Windows 8 on it and eventually upgraded to windows 10. The problem appeared long after and has been around for a while, I'm just now trying to get rid of it.

I should mention, I'm using the integrated keyboard and only my mouse is plugged on.

Here it is on Asus' website https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ROG-G750JH/

I have no idea how to diagnose or solve the issue whatsoever. Any help is welcomed :)

Comment: If you just press Win+R quickly and release it and then wait, does the Run dialog open eventually?

Comment: No, it does not. I think the Win release is "processed" before the R press.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page: Are you still holding the Win key down when you press R? The way it's supposed to be done is that you press Win first and hold it, then press R, then release them both together. Please confirm this is the case.

Comment: Pressing R while holding Win doesn't do anything if I don't keep Win pressed long enough.

Comment: A couple more things to try: Open Notepad and place your cursor in there, then press Win+R. Let us know if the "R" types out in Notepad if Win isn't held down "long enough". Next, do you have to hold down CTRL+ALT+DEL and CTRL+SHIFT+ESC the same length of time to make them activate their particular functions? Next, have you tried plugging in an external keyboard and seeing if it behaves the same way? Finally, have you performed any updates to your drivers, checked for application and OS updates, and checked your Task Manager to see if there are applications using a lot of resources?

Comment: Upon further testing, it appears that the time between presses and releases being processed is seemingly random, I noticed it in a game with one tap on W A S or D moving the character different distances each time. For shortcuts such as CTRL ALT DEL they work sometimes (randomly it seems, I guess I just had bad luck with Win R until now). Everything is up-to-date and only Windows Defender is busy at startup with 5% use of processor, and it stays so for a while after the issue no longer happens. I don't have another keyboard to use so I can't try that.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me! I just solved the issue by noticing this post https://superuser.com/questions/1061944/windows-10-keyboard-type-rate-extremely-slow-after-boot , which makes mine a duplicate. I have no idea how I missed it before. Fixing that issue also made my laptop boot and start in 3 seconds rather than 20... cool :)

Comment: Sounds like a good find and a great fix.